# ECharts- How to show horizontal scroll bar with 3 lines of legend, and after that scroll if items doesn't fit in 3 lines

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, linechart, echarts

I am using ECharts to show the trend data in line chart. I have 50 series to show in the line chart. Every series has a legend to show. I want to show the legends on top of the chart. But, I want to show the legends in maximum 3 lines. And if legends doesn't fit in the 3 lines then  I want to show the vertical scroll. But, I am not able to show the vertical scroll with maximum of 3 lines of legends. Every line should show more than one legend in it.

I tried with vertical and horizontal scroll. In vertical scroll, it shows only one legend in one line. this is the problem. Actually, ECharts should show the what ever possible legends in one line. If there is enough space to have 2 legends in one line, it should show 2 legends in one line. It should show 3 lines and if all legends doesn't fit in three lines, then should add vertical scroll. But, currently legends overlap to chart.

[image]

```
option = {

    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'item',
        formatter: '{a} <br/>{b} : {c}'
    },
    legend: [{
        left: 'left',width:'50%',
        type:'scroll',
        orient:'vertical',
        height:'100',
        selectedMode:'multiple',
        //pageButtonPosition:'end',
        //formatter:'legend {name} ',
        data: ['saaaaaaaaaaaaaaa0', 'saaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1','saaaaaaaaaaaaaaa2','saaaaaaaaaaaaaaa3'
        ,'saaaaaaaaaaaaaaa4','saaaaaaaaaaaaaaa8'
        , 'saaaaaaaaaaaaaaa9','saaaaaaaaaa10','saaaaaaaaaa13','saaaaaaaaaa14','saaaaaaaaaa11'
        , 'saaaaaaaaaa12','saaaaaaaaaa15','saaaaaaaaaa16'
        ,'saaaaaaaaaa17'],

    },
    {
        left: 'right',width:'50%',height:'auto',
        data: ['saaaaaaaaaaaaaaa5','saaaaaaaaaaaaaaa6','saaaaaaaaaaaaaaa7'],

    }
    ],
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        name: 'x',
        splitLine: {show: false},
        data: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
    },
    grid: {
       height:'auto'

    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'log',
        name: 'y'
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'saaaaaaaaaaaaaaa0',
            type: 'line',
            data: [1, 3, 9, 27, 81, 247, 741, 2223, 6669]
        },
        {
            name: 'saaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1',
            type: 'line',
            data: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256]
        },
        {
            name: 'saaaaaaaaaaaaaaa2',
            type: 'line',
            data: [1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32, 1/64, 1/128, 1/256, 1/512]
        },
          {
            name: 'saaaaaaaaaaaaaaa3',
            type: 'line',
            data: [1, 3, 9, 27, 81, 247, 741, 2223, 6669]
        },
        {
            name: 'saaaaaaaaaaaaaaa4',
            type: 'line',
            data: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256]
        },
        {
            name: 'saaaaaaaaaaaaaaa5',
            type: 'line',
            data: [1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32, 1/64, 1/128, 1/256, 1/512]
        },
          {
            name: 'saaaaaaaaaaaaaaa6',
            type: 'line',
            data: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256]
        },
        {
            name: 'saaaaaaaaaaaaaaa7',
            type: 'line',
            data: [1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32, 1/64, 1/128, 1/256, 1/512]
        },
              {
            name: 'saaaaaaaaaaaaaaa8',
            type: 'line',
            data: [1, 3, 9, 27, 81, 247, 741, 2223, 6669]
        },
        {
            name: 'saaaaaaaaaaaaaaa9',
            type: 'line',
            data: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256]
        },
        {
            name: 'saaaaaaaaaa10',
            type: 'line',
            data: [1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32, 1/64, 1/128, 1/256, 1/512]
        },
          {
            name: 'saaaaaaaaaa11',
            type: 'line',
            data: [1, 3, 9, 27, 81, 247, 741, 2223, 6669]
        },
        {
            name: 'saaaaaaaaaa12',
            type: 'line',
            data: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256]
        },
        {
            name: 'saaaaaaaaaa13',
            type: 'line',
            data: [1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32, 1/64, 1/128, 1/256, 1/512]
        },
          {
            name: 'saaaaaaaaaa14',
            type: 'line',
            data: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256]
        },
        {
            name: 'saaaaaaaaaa15',
            type: 'line',
            data: [1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32, 1/64, 1/128, 1/256, 1/512]
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you are trying to do something that is not supported by ECharts yet.

Programmatically speaking:

- You cannot get how many items are fit in one single line.
- For the reason above, you can't know how many lines you have in the legend block.
- There is no max-line or max-items-per-line control yet.

I guess the best you can do is to make 3 legend blocks that you place vertically with `legend.left` and `legend.top` pixel configurations, and put parts of your whole legend data into those blocks. The first `legend.data` would contain the first 3 items of your base array, the second `legend.data` would contain the 3 next ones... And control the contents externally by adding/removing items from each `legend.data`.

This is clearly not a good solution anyway. The scroll would look buggy.

I suggest you to post a clear example and use case of your idea on their [official feature request form](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-issue-helper/), this is the best way for you to get this functionality without coding a huge and unscalable workaround.

Comment: Thanks for your solution @Ryo. I have already added a request on that official form. here(https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/issues/10922) you can find it. But, I did not yet received any update from them. Will wait some more time...

About your another dirty solutions, those doesn't looks like to work for me. I need to handle the legend text click and legend colored circle click events also.such as on legend click, I want to hide the line and on legend circle click, I want to open another popup or something.

Comment: Hi @Ashok, yes I saw your issue when I posted mine on friday or something, I hope they consider your idea as a potential feature.
Regarding my dirty solution, it clearly won't handle your criterias since the click and scroll will get very limited. I bet it might be possible by coding further in plain js (to detect events inside the ECharts components) but it would take a hell lot of your time and effort, knowing it might not work at last. In that case if I were you, I would just code a wrapper component that takes a chart plus one handmade legend component that would be synced with the data.

Comment: Hi @Ryo, yes you are correct. I am planning to write my own HTML legend control which will work with Echart. Echart is already exposing the legend click events those I can fire from HTML legend color or legend text click. I hope this will work.. Thanks for sharing your inputs and experience..